# Woocommerce custom fields in product description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I use custom woocommerce product attributes / fields in the product description?

Like:

This is a %%color%% chair.

Color in this case is red.

I have been searching for hours, but can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shortcode in functions.php where you specify your logic and then use it within your description with the name of your choice. You got access to the global variable `$product`. `This is a [custom_shortcode_that_returns_the_color_of_the_product] chair.`